# Allowing User to add their own text fields

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, textbox, frontend

I was wondering if there is anyway I can include a button within my project that will allow the user to add an extra text field for them to type in.

I have a section which must allow the user to type in four options. However if more options are necessary they should be able to add more text boxes to allow this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED**

You mean something like this?

HTML

```
<div>Add Text box</div>
```

JQUERY

```
$("div").click(function () {
    if (!$("input").length) {
        $("div").after("<input><br>");
    }
});
```

I created a element that when u click it adds an input

https://jsfiddle.net/kLe5kLc3/2/

Comment: Hi, this works as I would like but the text boxes add below the button and again at the bottom of the screen

Comment: Where do you like them to be added?

Comment: Just under the "Add Text box" <div>. It does this fine but I noticed that when one is added under the <div>, it duplicates at the bottom of the screen

Comment: yes, I didn't limit the number of text boxes u could create since I didn't know the purpose. But i've updated the answer ;)

Comment: Sorry, I think there's some confusion. The text box adds perfectly fine under the <div> where it should do. However, when you click to add one, it adds under the div and at the bottom of the screen as well, resulting in two boxes in different places from the same button :)

Comment: In your page u shouldnt use "div" u should give a class to it, for example <div class="addtextbox"> . And then in  jquery you use $(".addtextbox") where ive put $("div") ;)

Answer (score 0):

This will add a input element to your form

```
$("#form-id").append($("<input>", {name:"element-name", value:"Preset value"}))
```

It means "grab the element with the id 'form-id' and append an input-element, with the name and value this and that". This action should be performed on the click of your button, either by running it directly "onclick" or wrap it in a function call